# I can't remove a class object from a list

Tags: python, list

So I have this list (Sheep is a class i created, requiring one parameter):

```
list = [Sheep(2), Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]
```

However, when I try to remove `Sheep(2)` (`list.remove(Sheep(2)`) from the list, it returns `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's because writing `Sheep(2)` twice creates 2 *different* instances of `Sheep`

Comment: What is the defintion of `Sheep` class ? Could you paste that ?

Comment: A few issues here: (1) Don't use a reserved word, i.e. list, as a variable name; (2) Your call to list.remove creates a new Sheep object, instead of referencing an existing one. I recommend using an index to remove the object or to name the objects before adding them to the list.

Comment: class Sheep:
    def __init__(self, camouflage_score):
        self.camo = camouflage_score

Comment: Do you want to remove all `Sheep` with value 2 from the list ?

Answer (score 3):

To test for membership in a python list with a custom class you must provide an equality (`__eq__`) method

```
class Sheep:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        assert isinstance(other, Sheep)
        return self.x == other.x
```

Now you can create instances of your class with the same "x" and they will be members of your list

```
foo = [Sheep(2), Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]
print(Sheep(2) in foo)  # True
```

And you should be able to remove them too

```
foo.remove(Sheep(2))
print(foo)  # [Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The two `Sheep(2)`s are different objects.

To let the the first `Sheep(2)` be found by comparing it to the second one,  define equality on your `Sheep`. Then

```
class Sheep: 
    def __init__(self, camouflage_score): 
       self.camo = camouflage_score          

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other and self.camo == other.camo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index to remove your objects.

```
x = object()
y = object()
array = [x, y]
array.pop(0)
# Using the del statement
del array[0]
```

Comment: But is it possible to remove a specific sheep? for example a sheep thats in the middle of the list (that you dont know the index) or how do you find out the index of a sheep?

Comment: Using this method, it's not possible!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
class Sheep: 
    def __init__(self,v): 
        self.v = v
```

When you create an instance:

```
In [3]: Sheep(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: <__main__.Sheep at 0x7fa5a7614550>

In [4]: Sheep(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: <__main__.Sheep at 0x7fa5a49bf4a8>
```

Look carefully at `0x7fa5a7614550` and `0x7fa5a49bf4a8`, They are different:

```
In [5]: Sheep(1) == Sheep(1)                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: False
```

That is because of creating instance, each  time you create an instance with same value, it does not mean that they are same.

but you can do something like this:

```
In [6]: Sheep(1).v == Sheep(1).v                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: True
```

so if you want to remove item with `v=2`, you can do this:

```
list_of_sheeps = [Sheep(2), Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]

new_list = [i for i in list_of_sheeps if i.v != 2] # v is the name of inner field. (self.v)
```

Then the `new_list` will be your desired result without `Sheep(2)`.

or using `filter`:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x:x.v != 2, list_of_sheeps))
```

Note that:

> Do NOT USE `list` as a name of variable. list is built-in name in python, you will override its own functionality.

Comment: is there a way to mention a specific sheep without using the index?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the other instances using a list comprehension by checking value like,

```
>>> list = [Sheep(2), Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]
>>> newl = [x for x in list if x.camo != 2] # will remove all Sheep with camo value == 2
```

For removing only one instance with the value, you can do something like,

```
>>> for idx, sheep in enumerate(list[:]):
...   if sheep.camo == 3:
...     list.pop(idx)
...     break
```

But i'd recommend you implement the `__eq__` method in your `Sheep` class and just do

```
>>> list.remove(Sheep(3))
```

And now the new list will be like,

```
>>> newl
[Sheep(3), Sheep(3), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(4), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(5), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(6), Sheep(7), Sheep(7), Sheep(8)]
```

Comment: can you remove just one? for example... if i want to remove just one Sheep(3)?

Comment: Sure. You can just implement `__eq__` method in your `Sheep` class and just remove `list.remove(Sheep(3))`